# actionbar with background from fragments

Tags: java, android, background, android-actionbar

Iam want to get the following to work:
I have an actionbar which contains 3 tabs. I can swipe them perfectly left and right. All 3 tabs have the same background image. Now my problem is, that the actionbar itself has a black background. I wish that the background image from the 3 fragments (which are all the same) is over the complete screen. So the actionbar should be transparent and have the background from the fragment. Is this possible?

really thank you!

Comment: no. why do you think i would do?

Comment: never mind. I just mixed you up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: I edited the answer after your last comment.

Take advantage of ActionBar overlaying. Since recent updates of support library v7 things need to be done in slightly different way then before. Modify your styles in the following way:

In res/values/styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

In res/values-v11/styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Use `AppTheme` as a theme of your application. In manifest add attribute for application tag `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`. Everything should work just fine and your ActionBar will be transparent from now on.

Comment: I don't know what iam doing wrong but the background of the actionbar is gray and not transparent. And it does not overlay the activity. Also if i change the style to:
<item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
does not change the color

Comment: If you still experience this problem, try to use older version of support library v7. Older then version 21 which introduces Material Design aspects. It can help you.

Comment: Is there a Link to previous Versions? I do not really find anything. Sorry for this much questions.

Comment: [Android support library archive](https://github.com/danielesegato/android-support-library-archive) Check android-support-library-archive/v7/appcompat/libs/ folder for android-support-v7-appcompat.jar. It is revision 18. To use that revision of support v7 library add the whole v7 folder as an Android library to your  project.

Comment: [EDIT] with a style i found  at another site i was able to get the overlay to work. but the actionbar is not transparent. i become crazy :/. The code i found on another site is:
   <style name="Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar.Overlay"
  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
  <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Holo.ActionBar.Overlay</item>
 </style>

<style
  name="Holo.ActionBar.Overlay"
  parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
  <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

Comment: oh no excuse me. I noticed that there is a difference between the actionbar and the part where my tab-names are shown. So: The actionbar is transparent but the 3 tabs that i click to switch the pages are not transparent. Their background is black.

Comment: Now I can't see the comment which you posted previously and in which you've written that everything works fine with previous version of support library v7 but I hope this is still a truth :) If so, great, I'm really happy that you finally made it. I did a little private investigation on that case and from what I can see since last updates of support v7 library action bar transparency and overlaying just doesn't seem to work. I found other posts on SO which confirmed that.

Comment: With last updates of support v7 library the brand new Toolbar from Material Design is introduced which can totally replace action bar. It can be customized in more flexible way than action bar and with toolbar transparency and overlaying works for me. I checked that in my code. So to gain desired effect with the newest version of support v7 you should use toolbar. Moreover tabs navigation in deprecated since Android API 21. However in your case there's probably no need to use the latest version of support v7 so you can stick to older version and have everything working properly.

Comment: I have to say that adding new functionality in new versions of support v7 like Toolbar is cool from Google's side, but breaking the previous functionality is a shame.

Comment: Hi michal.z, I hope you will read this:
I was able to notice that this line of code:
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
is the reason why my actionbar is not transparent. If i comment it out the actionbar is transparent. But if I remove this line, there are not tabs added to the actionbar :/ Do you know any solution for this behavior? Thank you!

Comment: On what revision of support library v7 have you experienced that? I think we should move our discussion to mail. You can find mine on my profile site.

Comment: Hi, I switch to Android Studio and wrote the following in die build.gradle file:
dependencies 
{
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}
so I think it is revision 18? If I change the 18 to 21 the overlay effect disapears. So it changes something. 


I can not figure out how to find your mail, sorry. I look everywhere in your profile :/.